# Failed to add record to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, syntax-error, addition

I'm sitting with this code for about 2 hours and I still dont know why it isnt working. Check this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO newsy (tytul, skrot, opis, cena, opinia, galeria, data_utw, extra, kategoria, wartosc_extra, jednostka, stan_magazynowy) VALUES ($tytul, $autor, $skrot, $opis, $data, $extra, $kategoria, $wartosc_extra, $jednostka, $stan_magazynowy)");
```

Every variable is correctlly passed and I can check all with echo, so the problem is here but I dont know exactly where. Thanks for your help

Comment: What error do you get OUT of the mysql query?  Oh, and standared `mysql_` is being deprecated, use `mysqli_` comment.

Comment: Just check the datatypes....normally the strings and datetime values goes between 'value'

Answer (score 0):

You're probably inserting strings, and have forgotten to quote them, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO newsy (tytul, ...) VALUES ('$tytul', ....)
                                       ^--    ^---
```

assuming you're using the deprecated mysql_*() functions, you would have noticed this if you had any sort of error handling on your queries:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing quotes around your variables, please change to this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO newsy (tytul, skrot, opis, cena, opinia, galeria, data_utw, extra, kategoria, wartosc_extra, jednostka, stan_magazynowy) VALUES ( '".$tytul."',  '".$autor."',  '". $skrot."',  '".$opis."',  '".$data."',  '".$extra."',  '".$kategoria."',  '".$wartosc_extra."',  '".$jednostka."', '". $stan_magazynowy."')");
```

The query will fail anyway since there are 12 fields and 10 variables to insert

Then I would like you to remember that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have 12 columns in (tytul, skrot, opis, cena, opinia, galeria, data_utw, extra, kategoria, wartosc_extra, jednostka, stan_magazynowy) and you are trying to insert only 10 values.

Answer (score 0):

First pass 12 value instead of 10
and surround value with single quote(') like '$tytul'